# How to create bins

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, bin

Currently I have bins created using the following code:

```
bin_volumes = [((i+1)**3 - i**3) * bin_width**3 *4 * np.pi/3 for i in range(num_bins)]
```

format of bins :

```
[(0.0, 0.10000000000000001), (0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001), (0.20000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004), (0.30000000000000004, 0.40000000000000002), (0.40000000000000002, 0.5), (0.5, 0.60000000000000009), (0.60000000000000009, 0.70000000000000007), (0.70000000000000007, 0.80000000000000004), (0.80000000000000004, 0.90000000000000002), (0.90000000000000002, 1.0), (1.0, 1.1000000000000001), (1.1000000000000001, 1.2000000000000002), (1.2000000000000002, 1.3), (1.3, 1.4000000000000001), (1.4000000000000001, 1.5), (1.5, 1.6000000000000001), (1.6000000000000001, 1.7000000000000002), (1.7000000000000002, 1.8), (1.8, 1.9000000000000001), (1.9000000000000001, 2.0), (2.0, 2.1000000000000001), (2.1000000000000001, 2.2000000000000002), (2.2000000000000002, 2.3000000000000003), (2.3000000000000003, 2.4000000000000004), (2.4000000000000004, 2.5), (2.5, 2.6000000000000001), (2.6000000000000001, 2.7000000000000002), (2.7000000000000002, 2.8000000000000003), (2.8000000000000003, 2.9000000000000004), (2.9000000000000004, 3.0), (3.0, 3.1000000000000001), (3.1000000000000001, 3.2000000000000002), (3.2000000000000002, 3.3000000000000003), (3.3000000000000003, 3.4000000000000004), (3.4000000000000004, 3.5), (3.5, 3.6000000000000001), (3.6000000000000001, 3.7000000000000002), (3.7000000000000002, 3.8000000000000003), (3.8000000000000003, 3.9000000000000004)
```

Format of data:

```
3.615                                                                                                                                                                                                          
4.42745271008                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2.55619101399                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2.55619101399                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2.55619101399                                                                                                                                                                                                  
4.42745271008                                                                                                                                                                                                  
3.615
2.55619101399
4.42745271008
5.71581687075
5.71581687075
3.615
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
2.55619101399
```

I want to be able to add one every time a data point fits in the range of a bin so that I can gather the "frequency" of each range and later use that to create a graph.

Code for creating data:

```
for b in range(2047):
    for a in range(b+1,2048):
        vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
        vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])

        x = vector1
        y = vector2
        vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))

        dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))

        dp = dotProduct**.5
        data = dp
```

Comment: Can you explain the format of the data more?  Are those lines in a file?  Are they values in a `numpy` array?  It's not clear.

Comment: Yes, here I will provide the code for creating the data set, but yes I believe it is a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a list of tuples, each of which defines the bounds of a bin:

```
bins = [(i*bin_width, (i+1)*bin_width) for i in range(num_bins)]
```

If you have a list of data values, like this:

```
data = [0.7, 2.8, 1.3]
```

Then you can count how many fall into each bin like this:

```
[sum([(value >= low) and (value < high) for value in data]) for low, high in bins]
```

Comment: Okay cool, and do you know what I can use to count how many data points fall in each bin?

Comment: Should probably make a new question for that, but it's close enough - I added another part to the answer above.

Comment: when I try that I get the error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: Is your `data` structure actually an array, or just a single number?  Because that error makes it sound like you're using just a single data value instead of an array of values. When you run `print data` what is the output?

Comment: I belive it is a single data output, I added sample data to question.

Comment: You should create a new question for this - it's confusing to have the two questions together.  I'll keep an eye out for the new one.

Comment: Can I just edit this question with all new content, because I can make another question for an hour

Comment: Of course you can, but it makes this question less useful to future users who might have a similar problem to you.  At the moment, I don't understand how your data is structured, so I can't advise you about how to bin the data.

Comment: Okay I changed the question and provided sample data and formats.